# Running a gpg shell script to decrypt a file via Automator

Tags: automator, script, gpg

I regularly need to decrypt a gpg-encrypted file (always the same) to simply view it in TextEdit. I have a very simple shell script for that. It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
outfile=`mktemp -t $$`  # Temporary file name
gpg --output $outfile --decrypt /path/to/file.gpg
open -a TextEdit $outfile
sleep 1
rm $outfile
```

When run from the terminal, all goes well. GPG asks for my passphrase in a pop-up window, TextEdit comes up, the temp file is deleted and all is great. Not so in Automator. I select "Run Shell Script", ignore the shell script input, paste the contents of the script (except for the first line). TextEdit pops up with a blank file and GPG never asks for the passphrase. I tried using the full path to GPG but that didn't do it. I know virtually nothing of Automator actions so the problem surely comes from me.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

The Automator “Run Shell Script” action runs the script in a non-interactive shell (for an explanation of the difference between interactive and non-interactive shells, see the [pertinent section of the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/intandnonint.html)) – there is, simply spoken, no terminal to get user input from. I suppose the `gpg` utility recognizes this and skips the password prompt (else your script would hang).

You should be able to pipe your passphrase to GPG inside such an action using the `--passphrase-fd 0` option (see [gpg’s man page](http://www.gnupg.org/gph/de/manual/r1023.html)) , however, i.e.

```
echo "passphrase" |  gpg  --passphrase-fd 0 --output $outfile --decrypt /path/to/file.gpg
```

You can securely store your passphrase in the OS X Keychain and retrieve it from there. Although possible via a shell script (the TextMate blog has [details on how to achieve that](http://blog.macromates.com/2006/keychain-access-from-shell/) – be sure to read the comments), there are so many gotchas to that I’d recommend  using a bit of AppleScript and Daniel Jalkut’s excellent *[Usable Keychain Scripting](http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/2035/usable-keychain-scripting-for-lion)* app. Once installed, the following bit of AppleScript will retrieve your password (assuming the account name is “GPG”):

```
tell application "Usable Keychain Scripting" to get password of first generic item of current keychain whose account is "GPG"
```

Either wrap it in an `osascript` shell command, i.e.

```
passphrase=$(osascript -e '<command above>')
```

or, as you are using Automator, add an AppleScript action, retrieve the passphrase inside it and pass it to the shell script.